# Apportable: "No xcodeproj or approj found in the current directory"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apportable

For some reason when I try to find my projects directory using terminal apportable cannot "Find" it. I always get the following error:

```
-bash: /Users/chrisgonzalez/Desktop/Rocks 4 2/Rocks.xcodeproj: is a directory
```

Chriss-MacBook-Air:~ chrisgonzalez$ apportable load
Error: No xcodeproj or approj found in the current directory.
Chriss-MacBook-Air:~ chrisgonzalez$

I drag and drop the .xcodeproj file into terminal, so im sure its the right path but for some reason it doesnt want to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: it is a directory. thats correct

Comment: Yeah but then it tells me that no xcodeproj is found in the directory @Sulthan

Comment: Get into the habit of avoiding spaces in filenames and paths for developer tools. Spaces need proper escaping to be handled correctly, one tool or script of many in a chain that doesn't handle spaces correctly suffices and things break. Try renaming "/Rocks 4 2/" to "/Rocks42/" and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to escape the path. Try

```
/Users/chrisgonzalez/Desktop/Rocks\ 4\ 2/Rocks.xcodeproj
```